# How to convert DStream[List[T]] to DStream[T]

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I am new to scala and spark streaming, and I have a question which confused me for hours:

Currently I generated a Dstream of list[T] , printed out as

```
List(PV(57,2,1448910200000,0xD13617EBC1032E0869C7,BI Office),
PV(57,2,1447200000000,0xD13617EBC1032E0869C7,UPS office),     
PV(100,2,1449900000000,0xD13617EBC1032E0869C7,BI Office), 
PV(57,2,1447200000000,0xD13617EBC1032E0869C7,UPS office))
```

Is there a way to convert this Dstream of list to a Dstream looks like

```
PV(57,2,1448910200000,0xD13617EBC1032E0869C7,BI Office) 
PV(57,2,1447200000000,0xD13617EBC1032E0869C7,UPS office)
PV(100,2,1449900000000,0xD13617EBC1032E0869C7,BI Office)
PV(57,2,1447200000000,0xD13617EBC1032E0869C7,UPS office)
```

And then I can convert it to a pairDStream and implement updateStateByKey function on the Dstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**flatMap**](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#transformations-on-dstreams) function of Dstream. It will create a new DStream by generating multiple new records from each record in the source.

```
val words:Dstream[List[T]] = { ........... }
val word:Dstream[T] = words.flatMap(list => list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dstream.flatMap(list => list)
```